# Jackson UntypedObjectDeserializer on Object.class deserealizes only Date Strings and not other strings

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

I am facing a very weird issue. I have the below implementation.

```
    objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("DateConverter");

    // register a new deserializer extending and replacing UntypedObjectDeserializer
    module.addDeserializer(Object.class, new CustomObjectDeserializer());
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

```
    public class CustomObjectDeserializer extends UntypedObjectDeserializer
    {
        private static final String JSON_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";
        private static final String UTC_STRING = "UTC";

        public CustomObjectDeserializer() {
            super(null, null);
        }

        @Override
        public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
        {
            if (p.currentTokenId() == JsonTokenId.ID_STRING)
            {
                final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(JSON_DATE_FORMAT);
                // Incoming dates need to be converted into UTC timezone.
                format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(UTC_STRING));
                try
                {
                    String value = p.getText();
                    System.out.println("Value : " + value);
                    return format.parse(value);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    return super.deserialize(p, ctxt);
                }
            }
            else {
                return super.deserialize(p, ctxt);
            }
        }
    }
```

For below JSON request:

```
{
      "field": "StartTime",
      "fieldType": null,
      "operator": "<=",
      "value": "2013-05-23T18:29:59.999Z",
      "connector": "AND",
      "parameterName": null
}
```

Output:

```
Value : 2013-05-23T12:59:59.999+0000
```

Why is only date type String fields getting deserialized here and not other strings. Also, to cross check I created another deserializer as StringDeserealizer which worked on String.class rather than Object.class and all the Strings including the Date Strings were deserialized with that.

Its so confusing. Why are the Strings not considered by the ObjectDeserealizer?

Comment: I tried your code (jackson 2.12.2) and it works fine, maybe some other part of your code can be the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing is you can do write a custom deserializer for `Date` only. Something like this,

```
public class CustomDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    
    private static final String JSON_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";
    private static final String UTC_STRING = "UTC";

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        String dateString = jsonparser.getText();
        final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(JSON_DATE_FORMAT);
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(UTC_STRING));

        try { return format.parse(dateString); }
        catch (Exception e) { return null; }
    }
}
```

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new CustomDateDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```